# Java: Swap objects

Tags: java

Suppose I have in Java regular objects without any special copy constructors etc. and I want to swap between the objects, is this will work:

```
MyObject objTmp;
objTmp = obj_1;
obj_1 = obj_2;
obj_2 = objTmp;
```

Or should I think about it like about references - `objTmp` is referencing to `obj_1` and after `object_1 = obj_2` eventually `objTmp` will point also to `obj_2` so the last line `obj_2 = objTmp` is useless and the swap failed? 
Thanks,

Comment: A picture speaks a thousand words, you can take a look at my solution.

Comment: @user3437460 Thanks good answer I got it...

Comment: You can apply the same concept on other seemingly confusing logic in Java. If it helps, you can consider accepting my solution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming obj_1 and obj_2 is not null.
Let me break down your code and see what is happening step-by-step:

```
+------+
| obj1 | <-----obj_1 
+------+
+------+
| obj2 | <-----obj_2 
+------+
```

> MyObject objTmp; (Creates an empty variable)

```
+------+
| obj1 | <-----obj_1 
+------+
+------+
| obj2 | <-----obj_2 
+------+

  null   <-----objTmp
```

> objTmp = obj_1;    (Let objTmp point to where obj_1 is pointing at)

```
+------+
| obj1 | <-----obj_1 
+------+ <-----objTmp
+------+
| obj2 | <-----obj_2 
+------+
```

> obj_1 = obj_2;    (Let obj_1 point to where obj_2 is pointing at)

```
+------+
| obj1 | <-----objTmp 
+------+ 
+------+
| obj2 | <-----obj_2 
+------+ <-----obj_1
```

> obj_2 = objTmp; (Let obj_2 point to where objTmp is pointing at)

```
+------+
| obj1 | <-----objTmp 
+------+ <-----obj_2
+------+
| obj2 | <-----obj_1 
+------+
```

**So, in the end, it does swap (references).**

Answer (score 1):

This is all about references, and therefore it works correctly.

After the first assignment, objTmp references the object referenced by obj_1.
After the second, obj_1 references the object referenced by obj_2, so it's good that the reference to the first object was saved into objTmp.

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Usually **Swap** deals with values.

Here you are just exchanging the references.

Answer (score 1):

### **It works.**

Try the below code snippet with `String` class objects.

```
public class Swap {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String first = new String("first");
    String second = new String("second");

    System.out.println(first + " :: " + second);

    String temp = first;
    first = second;
    second = temp;

    System.out.println(first + " :: " + second);
  }
}
```

**Output:**
first :: second
second :: first

> eventually `objTmp` will point also to `obj_2`.

This will not happen. Just because obj_1 is referencing to `obj_2` does not mean to update the reference in `objTemp`.

`objTmp` will always point to the reference which is explicitly assigned to it (`obj_1`).

Answer (score 1):

In `MyObject objTmp = new MyObject()`, `new MyObject()` is the actual object and `objTmp` is the **object reference variable which hols the address where your object is created**.

When you do `obj_1 = obj_2;` then essentially you are passing the memory address from one variable (or in this case object reference variable) to another one.

Now, let's say `objTmp` is holding some memory address `0x4` (please note that in your case it is not because you have not created the object)  and `obj_1` is holding memory address `0x8`, now when you do `objTmp = obj_1;` then essentially putting `0x8` in `objTmp`, which means that you are asking `objTmp` object reference variable to point to object at `0x8` memory address.

Same goes with your other code. So, whenever you do `obj_1 = obj_2;` basically you are asking your object reference variables to point to another object in memory. Now if `obj_1` is pointing to memory address of `obj_2` doesn't mean that `objTmp` will also point to memory address of `obj_2`, just because you did `objTmp = obj_1;`.

**Conceptually most important thing to understand is that** `objTmp`, `obj_1` are all object reference variables (ORV) and points to some memory location on the heap (or holds memory address on the heap). When you assign one ORV to other, you are just putting the memory location of one ORV into another.
Now, later in the code if you change the ORV to point to some other memory location (by constructing a new object or ORV assignment) then it doesn't mean that all other ORV to which you has assigned this ORV will also point to the new memory address.

Whether swap is achieved or not is concluded by @user3437460 and concept is explained here.

Comment: Whether swap is achieved or not is concluded by @user3437460 and concept is explained here.

Answer (score 1):

Yo uare assigning the value of the reference,not the reference itself.So ,the above logic is correct.